# Why does python-vlc (libvlc) drop frames in fullscreen on a Raspberry Pi 4 B?

Tags: python, libvlc, python-vlc

The fullscreen video is skipping frames and thus the stream was getting corrupted (some [I-frames](https://shopdelta.eu/h-264-image-coding-standard_l2_aid734.html) were dropped, leading to incomplete reconstruction of the video). This is with the following setup:

```
Raspberry Pi 4B
Python 3.11.2
python-vlc 3.0.20123
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was found here: [Using libVLC ignores disabled hardware acceleration](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=148022)

Setting the flag `--avcodec-hw=none` made the video run normally.

In the discussion in 2019, the worry was that libvlc was not taking programmatically set flags into account. But it seems to work now.

```
media = vlc.Media(VIDEO_PATH)
media.add_option(':avcodec-hw=none')
```

In [this thread](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=148957), users discuss libvlc not employing the optimizations that the Raspberry Pi -specific VLC application does. My hypothesis for why disabling hardware acceleration works is that the default acceleration employed by default by libvlc is somehow incompatible with RPi.

Comment: open a bug report and share your media sample. This is a workaround, not a fix.